# Error CEE9001 calling external stored procedure (RPGLE/AS400) from java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, db2-400, rpgle

I have a error when I run a stored procedure from java that call to a simple RPGLE program
If I run the SP from DB2 (System I navigator) is success or If i run the rpgle program is as400 return ok but when the SP is running  from java the first execution  is ok, the second execution return a error (CEE9901 - Application error. *N unmonitored by *N at statement*IN. instruction X'4000)
and I dont know why!. 
someone could help me?

this is my code
SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE WOOLB3.SP806012 (  
IN TRAMA CHAR(62) , 
INOUT RPTA CHAR(1) , 
INOUT VALOR CHAR(15) ) 
LANGUAGE RPGLE 
SPECIFIC WOOLB3.SP806012 
NOT DETERMINISTIC 
MODIFIES SQL DATA 
CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
EXTERNAL NAME 'WOOLB3/IR806012' 
PARAMETER STYLE GENERAL ; 

GRANT ALTER , EXECUTE   
ON SPECIFIC PROCEDURE WOOLB3.SP806012 
TO GRPAYP ; 

GRANT ALTER , EXECUTE   
ON SPECIFIC PROCEDURE WOOLB3.SP806012 
TO GRPCAL ; 

GRANT ALTER , EXECUTE   
ON SPECIFIC PROCEDURE WOOLB3.SP806012 
TO PUBLIC ; 

GRANT ALTER , EXECUTE   
ON SPECIFIC PROCEDURE WOOLB3.SP806012 
TO QPGMR ;
```

JAVA

```
Connection conn = null;
CallableStatement cs = null;
StringBuffer sbSQL = new StringBuffer();
String valor = "";

try {
    log.info("Inicio-->SP806012"); 
    conn = ResourceManager.getConnection(JNDIContext.JNDI_DATASOURCE_MCD);
    String esquema = FrameworkParameters.getValue(MCDConstant.ESQUEMA_RPG);
    sbSQL.append("{CALL ").append(esquema);
    sbSQL.append(".").append(MCDConstant.SP_OBTIENE_VALOR_CUOTA).append("(?,?,?)}");
    cs = conn.prepareCall(sbSQL.toString());            
    System.out.println(trama);
    cs.setString(1, trama);     
    cs.setString(2, MCDConstant.VACIO);
    cs.setString(3, MCDConstant.VACIO);
    cs.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
    cs.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);

    cs.execute();

    if (cs.getString(2).equals(MCDConstant.STRING_UNO)){
        valor = (String)cs.getString(3).trim();
    }                   

    log.info("Fin-->SP806012");

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new DAOException(e.getMessage(), e);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new DAOException(e);  
} finally{
    ResourceManager.callableStatementClose(cs);
    cs = null;
    ResourceManager.connectionClose(conn);
    conn = null;
}
return valor;
```

RPGLE

```
            z-add     *zeros        v_cuota          11 2           
            z-add     *zeros        v_mdiferi         1 0           
            move      '0'           v_mdiferi         1             
            move      *blanks       p_fecvcto         8             
            eval      ds_tarjeta = %trim(p_tarjeta)                 

 k_cs01p       chain     cs01pr                             70         
 70            eval      socic = ''                                    
               EXSR      sr_ObtRelDif                                  
               eval      p_fecvcto = fePROXVENC1(ds_tarjeta:v_mdiferi) 
               eval      v_cuota   = fegetcuota(p_ncuota:p_fcompra:    
                      p_fecvcto:p_capital:p_tea:socic)              

 v_cuota       ifgt      *zeros                                        
            movel     '1'           p_rpta                          
            endif                                                   
            move      v_cuota       p_valor
```

Comment: The request from Jairo for the joblog is good as a start. The CEE9001 exception only indicates that an error (at least one) happened and that you must review the log to find the detailed error messages from a deeper source. By running WRKOBJLCK against the DB2 user, you can locate the server job instances for that user (if any are still around after the error).